# IFile from String in java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, eclipse-plugin

I have a Map<String, String> containing the name of the file and content of the file. I want to create IFile for each of the entry in the map.

```
Map<String, String> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
fileMap.put("test1.txt", "Content of test1");
fileMap.put("test2.txt", "Content of test2");
```

How do I create IFile for each of the entries?

Comment: Are these files in the workspace? Only workspace files can be represented by an IFile.

Comment: No, these files aren't in my workspace.

Comment: Then you can't use IFile or most other Eclipse resource APIs. What do you want to do with the files?

Comment: I want to create a zip which contains these files.

Comment: Well if they are not in the workspace you just use normal Java file APIs such as Path, File, ZipFile, ...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what you said in your comments, this should do the work :

```
    Map<String, String> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
    fileMap.put("test1.txt", "Content of test1");
    fileMap.put("test2.txt", "Content of test2");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("multiCompressed.zip");
    ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> file : fileMap.entrySet()) {
        File fileToZip = new File(file.getKey());
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileToZip);
        writer.write(file.getValue());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName());
        zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        fis.close();
    }
    zipOut.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the `IFile` part of the question